# Google App Engine Send Grid PHP attachment

Tags: google-app-engine, sendgrid

I am trying to add attachments as shown on https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-google-php. But its not working by this way. I think I tried every possible solution but cant make this work. Here is my code.

```
<?php
require 'SendGrid_loader.php';

// Connect to your SendGrid account
$sendgrid = new SendGrid\SendGrid('myusername', 'mypassword');

// Make a message object
$mail = new SendGrid\Mail();

// Mail arrayi
$emails = array("mailadress1@test.com","mailadress2@test.com");
$names  = array("name1", "name2");


// Add recipients and other message details
$mail->setTos($emails)->
       setFrom('testsender@test.com')->
       setFromName('Test Sender')->
       setReplyTo('testemail@test.com')->
       setSubject('Test')->
       addAttachment("test.jpg")->
       addCategory("TEST-GONDERIM")->
       addUniqueArgument("BASIN", "YEREL-BASIN")->
       addSubstitution("%name%", $names)->
       setText('TEXT BODY MESSAGE')->
       setHtml('<strong>%name% MERHABA,</br>BODY MESSAGE</strong>');

// Use the Web API to send your message
$sendgrid->send($mail);
?>
```

I tried to put test.jpg file on the same folder with this php file. Also tried to add like gs://bucket_name/test.jpg but not working. Any ideas. Thanks in advance

Comment: What error message do you see?

Comment: I am not getting an error message; code sends an attachment with empty file.The file name is true but it has no content. When I open the file with notepad the file content is "@filename" or if I gave a different path "@path/to/file/filename". I also tried Curl version. But its not working either. I can run Curl version on different hosting and It works. But when it runs on google app engine It sends an file with empty content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with using web api v2 Curl version like this

```
$fileName = 'filename.pdf';
$image_data = file_get_contents('gs://my-bucket/filename.pdf');
```

sending part

```
$params = array(
'api_user'  => $user,
'api_key'   => $pass,
'x-smtpapi' => json_encode($json_string),
'to'        => 'email@yourdomain.com',
'subject'   => 'your subject',
'html'      => 'testing body',
'text'      => 'testing body',
'from'      => 'yourmail@yourdomain.com',
'files['.$fileName.']' => $image_data
 );

$request =  $url.'api/mail.send.json';
```